How to change Bitbucket User in Azure Pipeline?
A previous engineer set up our Azure pipelines with Bitbucket repositories.  He has left the company, his Bitbucket privileges were revoked, so the Azure pipelines can no longer reach Bitbucket.
Azure documentation says we should just be prompted for authentication when setting up a new pipeline to Bitbucket Cloud repository, (and that does work for me) but doesn't say how to update this connection on an existing pipeline.
We use the build number as part of our software version number that feeds into our quality system, I'd rather fix the existing pipelines and keep our build number sequence rather than have to change the minor version on 24 projects to accommodate resetting the build number counter by just deleting and re-adding all the pipelines.
How do I replace the other engineer's credentials with my own?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines   -  We do have persistCredentials: true  but I don't know if we can re-generate credentials by changing this to false.

If you have admin access to the project, you can also update the existing connection and all the pipelines using that connection will be updated at the same time.
Use a Private/Incognito browser tab if trying to set up a service account connection.

Go to the project page
Project Settings
Service Connections
Select a connection
Edit
Change - This will auto log in with existing Bitbucket connection or prompt for Bitbucket credentials.
Save & Close Edit


I found it in the GUI.

Pipelines -> Select Pipeline -> Edit -> … menu -> Triggers –> YAML tab -> Get sources -> Authorized using connection {old connection} Change
Re-select the repository
Save

It's advisable to use a service account for the new connection that won't go away when the company has turnover.
